# 403 error in files while hosting drupal site in hostgator

Tags: files

I'm trying to host my drupal site in Hostgator. Here what i've done so far:
a. uploaded files to server, created db and user and imported too.
b. Change settings.php database content.

My site is up and running although my css and files are not being loaded..when i check my browser console it shows 403 error, even i can't access my backend whenever i try to access it shows 404 error,although it seems to be working fine on my localhost.. i know it's permission problem but i don't know how to deal with it is there any steps i leftover which i need to follow[image], is there any step by step documentation on hosting drupal site on cpanel any help would be great.Thanks in advance.

P.S.-i'm using nginx, and linux system for my development environment.
And new to drupal :)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a problem with loading static files, and wouldn't be different if these CSS would be Wordpress-created or manual. You should rather contact your hosting company, they are the ones who have technical means to know the reason behind your issue.

Comment: static :( could you elaborate in what logic you mean by static it's an e-commerce site build by drupal commerce and by other different modules..although thanks for your concern

Comment: I mean that this file was uploaded there and just sits on the server's filesystem. It's not created dynamically by Drupal's PHP.

Comment: i don't think by any mean you understood my last reply it was  site created by drupal and almost every files are dynamically created with drupal using several module and problematically...any way thanks for you concern hoping for better answer :) kudos

Comment: Sorry, but that (usually) does not work like that. Drupal themes provide CSS files. They are just regular files that sit in `<webroot>/sites/*/themes/<theme name>`. And they are accessed like any other CSS you would ever upload to your server. OK, if you turn on CSS aggregation, Drupal creates aggregated CSS files - but then again they are just files on server's disk, accessed in good old regular way. Unless, of course, something generates them dynamically, but that's an exception and you should describe it with greater detail if we are to help you. First step: URI of resources that fails.

Comment: well my problem is with the drupal right permission on every files and folder in drupal i guess since it's 403 error..i just wanted to know is there anyway i could bulky manage the file permission of hosted file so that it meets drupal standard on server side..like something like script if so how am i suppose to do...i'm kind of lost over here.The site i'm trying to host is www.drupalizenepal.com

Answer (score 0):

Read up on the basics of linux permissions. Figure out which user nginx is running under. Make sure that user has read access on files and read/execute access on directories.